# Connecting to Sharepoint using Microsoft365R error

Tags: r, microsoft365r

I am trying to connect to sharepoint to load excel files within an unattended R script using the package Microsoft365R

I have created the app within Azure, and assigned it permissions. I have been able to successfully connect to a users onedrive and list the files within it.

Code that works

```
library(AzureGraph)
library(Microsoft365R)

tenant <- "your-tenant-here"

# the application/client ID of the app registration you created in AAD
# - not to be confused with the 'object ID' or 'service principal ID'
app <- "your-app-id-here"

# retrieve the client secret (password) from an environment variable
pwd <- Sys.getenv("EXAMPLE_MS365R_CLIENT_SECRET")

# retrieve the user whose OneDrive we want to access
# - this should be their 'userPrincipalName', which is of the form 'name@tenant.com'
# - note this may be different to their regular email address
user <- Sys.getenv("EXAMPLE_MS365R_TARGET_USER")

# create a Microsoft Graph login
gr <- create_graph_login(tenant, app, password=pwd, auth_type="client_credentials")

drv <- gr$get_user(user)$get_drive()

drv$list_files()
```

When running the below code, i get the error

```
# the application/client ID of the app registration to use
app <- "your-app-id-here"

# get the service account username and password
user <- Sys.getenv("EXAMPLE_MS365R_SERVICE_USER")
pwd <- Sys.getenv("EXAMPLE_MS365R_SERVICE_PASSWORD")

# SharePoint site and path to folder
sitename <- Sys.getenv("EXAMPLE_MS365R_SPO_SITENAME")
folderpath <- Sys.getenv("EXAMPLE_MS365R_SPO_FOLDERPATH")

# use the 'resource_owner' auth type for a non-interactive login
site <- get_sharepoint_site(sitename, tenant=tenant, app=app, username=user, password=pwd,
    auth_type="resource_owner")
```

Output:

```
Error in process_aad_response(res) : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401). Failed to obtain Azure Active Directory token. Message:
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
```

The function doesn't appear to have an argument for client secret.

I have followed the vignettes within the package, but i must be missing something. Is anyone able to provide assistance?

Resource
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/scripted.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the `AADSTS7000218` error when you try to get an authentication token for an application with the "Web" platform configuration without the `client_secret` parameter.

How about when the platform configuration of the application to `Mobile and desktop applications` ?

To change the platform configuration:

- Open the application from `App registrations` page on Azure AD, and open `Manage` - `Authentication` page.
- Delete the existing `Web` platform configuration.
- Open `Add a platform` and select `Mobile and desktop applications`.